# Unable to execute "doctrine:fixtures:load"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am running Symfony 2.8.7 on my local machine. I installed Data Fixtures using composer and I am not able to execute following command:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

It tells me there are no commands defined in the "doctrine:fixtures" namespace. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check if you enabled the bundle in the appkernel class

Comment: Have you adde the undle to `AppKernel.php`?

Comment: That did it. Thank you guys.